# Check if div has less than two children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just started using jQuery, and can't get my head around this.

I need to check if a div contains anything *but* a h3 header tag.

The structure of the html is as follows:

```
<div id="myContainer">
<h3>A header that is always present</h3>
any html, plain text or empty
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
if ( $("#myContainer h3:only-child") ) {
  $("#myContainer").css("display", "none");
}
```

The above will simply hide the div if there is no other html elements present, which is not what I intend since it will also contain plain text. I have tried with other selectors and functions, but I just can't seem to get it right.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should never use a bare jQuery object in the `if` clause since it is always "truthy". If you want to check whether there any matches, use `$(...).length > 0`.

Comment: Have you tried children() with .not('h3')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a function which will tell you if the div contains just H3 or also has other elements. I don't think there is a direct jQuery selector for that, so I wrote a simple function to checkForJustH3.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/BuqYN/2/) - That shows how to hide div that just has H3.

Check out the below demo by editing the div contents and Hit Run to see the result.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/BuqYN/1/)

```
function containsJustH3 (el) {
   var result = true;
    $(el).contents().each (function() {
        if (this.nodeName != 'H3') {
            //check for blank line or empty spaces
            if (this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) == '') {
                return true;
            }                
            result = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

And using the above function you can do something like,

```
if ( containsJustH3("#myContainer") ) {
  $("#myContainer").css("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! This seems to be working perfectly! I will test it out on my website tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#myContainer").children('h3').hide();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BuqYN/)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the 'plain text' in a p element and use this selector:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4bcq/)

```
$("#myContainer").children().not('h3').hide();
//Select all children but not the h3
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <h3>A header that is always present</h3>
    <p>any html, plain text or empty</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using it on a commercial webshop system, so I can not wrap the text in a <p> element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the length property to see how many children the div has

```
$("#myContainer").children('h3').length
```

Comment: This is not what he's asking, as `.length` does not include text nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work for plain text within the container `div` though.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem here is that jQuery methods like `children` will not get text nodes.  If you want to see how many children a div has, and include the text nodes, you'll want to grab the actual **dom node**, and check the length of its `childNodes` property.  This will include text nodes.

```
if ($("#myContainer")[0].childNodes.length > 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $cont=$('#myContainer'), $children=$cont.contents().not('h3');
if( ! $children.length) {
     $cont.hide();
}
```

Using contents() method will check if there are tags or text nodes in element, check if the children object has length, if not hide the container

Comment: You have to be careful, because in his example, there are 5 nodes: `\n`, `<h3>`, `\n`, `<p>`, and `\n`

Comment: It seems that this does the trick. I just had to write it like this:

`var $cont=$('#myContainer'), $children=$cont.contents().not('h3');
if( $children.text() === '') {
     $cont.hide();
}`

Does this seem to be a viable solution?

Comment: I beleive so yes...or $.trim( $children.html())==''

Comment: trim to remove whitespace from html, if the line breaks are an issue may have to use some regex to really clean things up

Comment: @charlietfl Doesn't seem like working http://jsfiddle.net/skram/BuqYN/3/ I think you going to need to check for other elements .contents. Check my answer below, but I am not sure if this can be achieved just using selectors.

Comment: Thanks! Just a final question - would it be easy to do the same check for a #otherContainer at the same time? The structure of #otherContainer is exactly the same as #myContainer.

Comment: Actually, I also see a problem. Ideally it should not remove the div when it is containing "And some other text", but it seem to work on my website for some reason.

Comment: To be honest for a bulletprooof solution based on text vs elements, you should probably put a regex filter in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#myContainer").contents().length` to get the number of nodes, including text nodes.  ***However***, this includes the newline before the `<h3>`, etc.